# Decoding Firebase base64 Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, firebase, decode

I'm trying to load an image stored in a Firebase server. I was checking other answers but I couldn't find why I'm getting a nil after being able to print the right String value:

In my application I have the following data structure:

[image: Structure]

And here the code I'm using to load it (The **nil** value is the one shown on the comment)

```
let profileDetailsRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users/" + sessionUserID + "/details")

    profileDetailsRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in 
        self.txtUsername.text = sessionUserID
        self.txtDisplayName.text = snapshot.value.objectForKey("nameToDisplay") as? String

        let base64EncodedString = snapshot.value.objectForKey("userImage")! as! String

        print(base64EncodedString) //Here it's printing well because I get the same value as shows in the dasboard so it finds it

        //But the value "decodedData" here below is returning **nil**
        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString as! String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())

        let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)!

        self.imageUserImage.image = decodedImage

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a lot easier to use an image hosting API like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and simply store the URL in Firebase.

That said, the problem is likely that your encoding and decoding options don't match. Try just providing `[]` in each options field. For example, to encode:

```
let image = [#Image(imageLiteral: "icon.png")#] // your UIImage
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! // or however you store your image
let base64EncodedString = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

And to decode:

```
if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString, options: []),
   let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
    // do something with decodedImage
}
```

If that doesn't work, Firebase may be truncating your image because the string length exceeds their limits.

This approach isn't a great way to store and load images — you miss out on HTTP caching, content types, server-side optimizations, etc. — so I'd try to avoid if you can.

Comment: I upvoted after I'd read the first sentence of your answer. The rest might be good too, but that point alone was worth it. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron, that was the problem. I was comparing the code with other posts and I was not realizing that the problem was not the code, was that I was using different ways to encode and decode. Thanks also for the advice about the hosting API.  I'll try it definitely the next time.